# navigate in iPhone app without programming

Tags: iphone

is it possible please to build small application with interface builder without coding, just to make sure that my interfaces are well organised ?

Comment: sounds like you should publish in the iBookStore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface Builder is a layout tool for individual screens. Connecting them in a navigation flow happens in code.

I second @fluchtpunkt's comment that you might want to look at publishing your content as an iBook rather than a native app. Or you could look at one of the html-to-native-app solutions like PhoneGap or Appcellerator. I've never worked with either of them, but theoretically if you have any HTML ability at all, they flatten out the learning curve of simple app building very significantly.

Answer (score 2):

For the navigation interface, no. You need to programmatically push views into the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test your interface you should probably use a mockup tool. I have good experience with blueprint. Or try something like interface (http://www.lesscode.co.nz/interface). Here you can create a GUI prototype and export it to XCode (maybe you can run the app at the simulator with navigation after this operation…) but i don’t know because i haven’t any experience this tool!